# convert from sentiment labels confidence to score

Tags: sentiment-analysis

as a beginner was checking for some sentiment analysis apis and found that google cloud returns a single sentiment value whereas aws returns 3 labels confidence.
Is there any way to convert the sentiment labels confidence from something like this `{'positive': 0.94, 'neutral': 0.02, 'negative': 0.04}` to a single sentiment score, a float value?
thx

Answer (score 0):

The common approach is to subtract the negative label score from the positive label score (no need for neutral). As follows:

```
final_score = positive_score - negative_score
```

The final score ∈ [-1, 1], -1 being very negative and 1 very positive.